# How to customize mu4e-context's shortcut?

Tags: mu4e

mu4e-switch-context seems to set shortcut key from first letter of its name.

How can I customize this to other letter?

e.g.) I have contexts like "work-A", "work-B", "work-C", ... and pressing ";" shows them all like [w]ork-*.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty maneer to obtain what you want is simply to choose your context name in order to have them begining with different letters. Say, in your case `A-work`, `B-work`, `C-work`. Or maybe more meaningfull name. I don't know why you have 3 different work context, but I could imagine they address 3 different customer. They probably have different name, so you could name your contexts after them, i.e. `Bob-customer1`, `Alice-customer2` etc.

If you really want to keep the names `work-A`, `work-B` etc., another way is simply to put the desired shortcut letter at their begining. I.e. `awork-A`, `bwork-B`. You should now see `[a]work-A` and `[b]work-B` when trying to select a profile.

Comment: personally, i've got so many mail-accounts that i don't want a single character to be a shortcut for a mail-account. i'd rather prefer something like `completing-read` or so. how could that be done?

Comment: a hear hear here. I have two email accounts gmail and  gmx and I want "x" to select gmx.